# Leksah: automatically build and/or reinstall dependencies when changed

Tags: haskell, build, makefile, ghc, leksah

I'm going to work on a project where I will need to work on both the dependencies and the dependent project at the same time. I have arranged it so that the dependencies lies in separate repos side by side with my dependent program.

Now, if I make a change in a dependency I would like this change to automatically "be recognized" in the dependent project. I imagine that I can accomplish this by either (1) edit  the ghc search path used by leksah to point at the dependency repo (how?) or (2) by making the  dependency to get automatically reinstalled on the system upon change (how?).

What is the neatest way to manage this?

(It's my first haskell project of this scale and my first project in Leksah)

Comment: Progress so far: I haven't got it working yet, but I now believe the best solution is to use [cabal-dev](https://github.com/creswick/cabal-dev) that sets up some kind of sandbox environment for my packages. I haven't looked into it that much yet though.
Also, the [cabal user guide](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/) have been useful. The --inplace and --package-db flags may be usable for sandboxing/creating a local package db.